# dozer one way mapping abs value

Tags: dozer

Here is my dozer field mapping

```
<mapping>
        <class-a>com.some.classA</class-a>
        <class-b>com.some.classB</class-b>
        <field type="one-way">
                <a>referenceId</a>
                <b>mediaId</b>
        </field>
    </mapping>
```

Both referenceId and media Id are of type Long and referenceId is not null value. 
I want to ensure that media Id is Math.abs(referenceId).
 Is it possible to do this in dozer mapping xml ?

Answer (score 0):

I need to use custom converter for this. The converter class must extend 
 AbstractDozerCustomConverter.